# Найти сумму ключей этого массива и поделить ее на сумму значений

Tags: php

```
 1. $arr = [1 => 6, 2 => 7, 3 => 8, 4 => 9, 5 => 10];
```

Найти сумму и поделить не проблема , проблема в том , что получалось
это только со строковыми '', а вот с числами не получается. в чем
моя ошибка?

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $elem){    
    $sum1 =$key[0]+$key[1]+$key[2]+$key[3]+$key[4]; 
    var_dump($sum1);  
}
```

Comment: покажите ваш код, ошибку или проблему результата

Comment: все в вопрос, тут невозможно смотреть код

Comment: Поправил как вы сказали

Comment: вам надо почитать про циклы. прям любой учебник. то, что сейчас написано - совсем никуда не годится

Comment: Нужно заново перечитывать?

Comment: Конечно. Потому что вы не понимаете зачем цикл делаете и при этом пишите `$key[0]+$key[1]+$key[2]+$key[3]+$key[4]; `  и не понимаете что хранится в key и в elem

Comment: да, и очень внимательно, чтобы понимать, что в данном случае будет в key и зачем там elem. Вам стоит выбросить суммирование, а поставить в цикл печать `echo "key = {$key} elem = {$elem}"` И посмотрите, что там будет

Comment: а какой учебник посоветуете ?

Comment: да банально хоть документацию посмотри на php.net   ....... по foreach  ( https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php ) ... это самое простое...... а так обычно советуют PHP 7. Дмитрий Котеров, Игорь Симдянов.

Comment: спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
$keys_sum = 0; // общая сумма ключей
$elements_sum = 0; // общая сумма элементов
foreach ($arr as $key => $element) { // $arr - ваш массив. $key и $element - ключ и элемент массива соответственно, на котором foreach сейчас находится
    $keys_sum += $key; // прибавляем в общую сумму текущий ключ
    $elements_sum += $element; // прибавляем в общую сумму текущий элемент массива
}
$result = $keys_sum / $elements_sum;
```

проходитесь по каждому элементу массива через цикл foreach. Прибавляете значение текущего ключа в общую сумму всех ключей, прибавляете значение текущего элемента массива в общую сумму всех элементов массива, затем уже делаете то, что вам нужно

Comment: я не сильно удивлен, что вы знаете, как это написать. Возможно, даже похитрее бы написали - `echo array_sum(array_keys($arr)) / array_sum($arr);` Но зачем, автор же пошел разбираться, а вопрос с принятым ответом никогда не будет удален

Comment: @splash58 мне кажется можно проголосовать за закрытие, а потом за удаление. Мне на ен-сайте как-то подкузьмили разок таким образом)

Comment: @u_mulder я думал, что только если автор сам удалит, а так - нет. Но возможно, мои девичьи грезы

Comment: пытался удалить, старание тех кто ответил не позволяют удалить. могу только пообещать что разберусь  , и буду старательно учится

Answer (score 0):

```
//Здравствуй. На циклах, это конечно хорошо, но вряд ли ты бы в проекте так растягивал код.
$a = [1=>2, 2=>3, 3=>4];
echo array_sum(array_keys($a));//для значений array_values
//Этот вариант, если со встройками.
$sum = null;
foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    $sum += $key; // или можно $sum = $key + $key
}
echo $sum;
//Это если на циклах. Такой foreach стандарт для пробега по массивам, как в других языках не знаю, но в php точно.
```

Comment: Прикольно, спасибо,я все понял, но видать надо удалить задание и фундаментально разобраться. :)